# Sublime Text 3 indents an extra tab after hitting enter for only parentheses in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Right now, I am working on a project using ReactJS in Sublime Text. Whenever I hit enter in between the parentheses it would break to another line and add an extra space. Here's an example:

**Initial Start**

The cursor is in the middle, then I hit enter:

[image]

**Current Result**

Then it adds this extra indent afterwards. Causing me to waste time and fix it.

[image]

**Desired Result**

This is my desired result after hitting enter:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What plugins/extensions (if any) are you using for React/JSX/JavaScript language support?

Comment: Just using Emmet and JavaScript Babel Syntax Highlight

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`** and add the following:

```js
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\t$0\n"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\($", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\)", "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

If the file was previously empty, add square brackets `[ ]` around the key binding and save. If the file has other custom key bindings, paste it at the beginning just after the opening bracket `[`, and make sure you add a comma `,` after it to make sure the file is valid [JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea.