# After pressing Enter not getting extra line Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, newline, indentation, key-bindings, sublime-text-plugin

I have this initial starting scene, where `|` denotes my cursor:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){|}
```

Result after hitting Enter:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
|}
```

Desired result:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    |
}
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833826/sublime-text-3-indents-an-extra-tab-after-hitting-enter-for-only-parentheses-in) but it didn't resolve my issue.

I have used following keybinding but it didn't work:

```json
[
   { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\t$0\n"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "{$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^}", "match_all": true }
        ]
    }
]
```

Also my these key binding are set to following:

```json
"auto_indent": true, 
"smart_indent": true, 
"indent_to_bracket": true,
"trim_automatic_white_space": true,
```

How can I fix it?
Edit:- I uninstalled Sublime Text4 and installed Sublime Text3. It;s working fine. I will stick to it.

Comment: In the linked solution, did you change () to {} to match your use case?

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora Yes I did that. But didn't worked :(

Comment: There's already a default key binding that does this, but it requires `auto_indent` to be turned on (as does the key binding in the solution you liked). Do you have that enabled? (if not, turn it on and remove the binding you added).

Comment: @lazy_propagator Can you please [edit] your question and paste in the keybinding code you tried but didn't work? Thanks.

Comment: @MattDMo I have added it.

Comment: @OdatNurd Yes it's already enabled. I have put some more enabled key binding.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are special characters in regular expressions, so you need to change the `"regex_contains"` `"operand"` to reflect that. The full keybinding should be:

```json
[
   { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\t$0\n"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
        ]
    }
]
```

If you want the same behavior to occur with square brackets `[ ]`, you need to escape them in the same way, as they are also special characters in regex.

#### EDIT

Here is the keybinding copied directly from Sublime Text 3, which is also the same in ST4:

```json
[
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
]
```

Comment: I don't why but It still didn't resolve my issue :(

Comment: I don't know if there is wrong with my sublime text or what. This also didn't work for me. I wish I could upload live video here. I am getting the same thing.

Comment: If you've upgraded to Sublime Text 4, please restart it in [Safe Mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/safe_mode.html), and add just this keybinding.

Comment: Yes I have upgraded to sublime 4, even if I started it in safe mode and did the process It gave same result. Btw In safe mode a windows poped up saying all the data/package/installation will be erased after closing this. So what is the point of doing this if I have to do this change again agian. Anyway still it didn't work.                    Tell me one thing if I will go back to Sublime Text3 will this problem disappear? I shouls try that once.

Comment: @lazy_propagator did you include the opening and closing square brackets? That's the only thing I can think of right now. As far as Safe Mode goes, it's designed to be a fresh slate for debugging single issues - you can run just one plugin without interference from others you may have installed, for example. Once you close it, it reverts back to that fresh slate. Remember, you can have multiple instances of Sublime running at once, so you could have one in safe mode and another in regular if you want.

Comment: Yes of course I included sqare bracket. This issue was not with sublime Text3. I will install a new one and then I will use your plugin If there is any issue and will let you accoordingly. Thanks for helping this far.